# Termplots in GAMLSS

Tags: mgcv, gamlss

I am interested in plotting the marginal effects in my GAMLSS model. However, what puzzles me a bit is that when using the `term.plot()` function from the `gamlss` package I do get estimates for the baseline category of a factor as well. However, when fitting a GAM model with the package `mgcv` the baseline category is always set to zero, which is also more intuitive to me.

Underneath you can find a worked out example using the `rent` dataset from the `gamlss` package. The two factor variables are `loc` (1 = location below average, 2 = average location, 3 = location above average) and `H` (0 = no central heating, 1 = central heating) and `A` (year of construction) as well as `Fl` (floor space in meters) are modelled as P-Splines.

```
library(mgcv)
library(gamlss)

r <- gamlss(R ~ pb(Fl) + pb(A) + H + loc, family = GA, data = rent)
summary(r)
term.plot(r, pages = 1)

r2 <- gam(R ~ s(Fl, bs = "ps") + s(A, bs = "ps") + H + loc, family = "Gamma"(link = "log"), data = rent)
summary(r2)
termplot(r2)
```

**GAMLSS-Output:**

```
Family:  c("GA", "Gamma") 

Call:  gamlss(formula = R ~ pb(Fl) + pb(A) + H + loc, family = GA,      data = rent) 

Fitting method: RS() 

------------------------------------------------------------------
Mu link function:  log
Mu Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.0851197  0.5692315   5.420 6.70e-08 ***
pb(Fl)       0.0103084  0.0004031  25.573  < 2e-16 ***
pb(A)        0.0014062  0.0002893   4.861 1.26e-06 ***
H1          -0.3008111  0.0225869 -13.318  < 2e-16 ***
loc2         0.1886692  0.0299295   6.304 3.58e-10 ***
loc3         0.2719856  0.0322862   8.424  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
Sigma link function:  log
Sigma Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.00196    0.01559  -64.27   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: Additive smoothing terms exist in the formulas: 
 i) Std. Error for smoothers are for the linear effect only. 
ii) Std. Error for the linear terms maybe are not accurate. 
------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of observations in the fit:  1969 
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  11.21547
      Residual Deg. of Freedom:  1957.785 
                      at cycle:  3 
 
Global Deviance:     27683.22 
            AIC:     27705.65 
            SBC:     27768.29 
******************************************************************
```

**GAM-output:**

```
Family: Gamma 
Link function: log 

Formula:
R ~ s(Fl, bs = "ps") + s(A, bs = "ps") + H + loc

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.52315    0.02850 228.919  < 2e-16 ***
H1          -0.30031    0.02292 -13.102  < 2e-16 ***
loc2         0.18877    0.02972   6.351 2.65e-10 ***
loc3         0.27184    0.03210   8.468  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(Fl) 1.723  2.136 309.3  <2e-16 ***
s(A)  3.777  4.410  21.4  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.376   Deviance explained = 36.7%
GCV = 0.13924  Scale est. = 0.13255   n = 1969
```

Noe that the estimates are relatively close to another for both methods. Baseline categories are `loc1` (below average location) and `H0` (no central heating).
However, when displaying the marginal effects via termplots, the GAM sets the effect of the baseline categories at zero, whereas the GAMLSS estimates an own effect for the baselines. I tried to reproduce this estimated effect but I am not sure how it is computed and why it is not left at zero?

**Termplots-GAMLSS:**
[image: Termplots from gamlss package]

**Termplots-GAM**
[image: Termplots from mgcv package]

I have already searched the literature, but I could not find an explanation of why the `term.plot` function is not placing the baseline effect at zero.

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

What is important is the extra effect for levels (other that the base level), which are the same for gamlss and mccv, as seen by the fitted parameter effects.

Again in the term plot, the difference between a level effect and the base level) is what is important, and is the same in the gamlss and mccv plots.

The gamlss term.plot() is centred at 0 vertically at a weighted average of the level effects (rather that the base level).